# To create a dead-end "burning mechanism" contract for a specific native token

Tags: smart-contract, native-assets, cardano-address, burn

I am not sure how this should, or could, be done on Cardano...

I would like an address/script which, if a specific native token were submitted there, that token would become permanently irretrievable.

The goal is to effectively "burn" specific tokens so they are no longer considered as a part of the circulating supply of that token.  The policy used to create them is closed, so truly using the mint/burn mechanism is no longer possible.

I am seeking advice/guidance/examples of a way to transparently, and verifiably remove some of these tokens from circulation.

- It should be irreversible.
- It should only be for a specific token.
- It should be possible for anyone to verify for themselves on-chain, that the tokens are truly locked irreversibly.

How can this be done?
Also, if there are more ways than one, what are the pros & cons of doing it one way vs another?

Thank you for helping me get this question answered!